# Joining process during quitting - Tkinter + multiporcessing

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, multiprocessing

I'm writing a GUI application that has a button which invokes a long task. In order for it not to freeze the GUI I delegate the task to a different process using python 3.3's multiprocessing module. Then I return the result for display using a Pipe.

I want the application not to leave any zombie process even if quit during the computation. As I'm on a mac this can happen one of two ways: through quitting the application (Command+Q) or but closing it's window.

Here's the code in the function linked to a button in the GUI:

```
main_pipe,child_pipe=Pipe()
p=Process(target=worker,args=(child_pipe,data))
p.start()
try:
    while not main_pipe.poll():
        root.update()

    value_array=main_pipe.recv()
finally:
    p.join()
```

This doesn't work the application doesn't respond to Command+q, and closing the window leaves two zombie process running (one for the GUI and one for the worker).

How to make it work in the other case as well?
Is this good practice? Is the a nicer, more pythonic way of doing it?

Additionally at the very end of the script I have those two lines (the exit() closes the application if the window is closed while not processing anything):

```
root.mainloop()
exit()
```

And finally, what's the difference between update() and mainloop()? Is it only that the latter hogs up the program while update() doesn't?

Comment: Have you tried adding an Except: operation that manually stops the processes upon an exception?

Comment: I've just tried that and it has the same effect. (I assume by saying stop the process you mean p.join())

Comment: try using the os.kill(processid,sig) method

Comment: it works when closing the window, but Command+Q doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally solved it. Although I not complete sure regarding this method's pythoness or side effects, if somebody needs it here it is.

I figured that quitting correctly can only happen in a mainloop() not in a update() so I wrote two functions, one for creating the process, and one for checking it's output and they call each other using root.after(). I set the processes daemon flag to true to ensure proper quitting behaviour. Here's the code:

```
def process_start():

    global value_array
    global main_pipe


    main_pipe,child_pipe = Pipe()

    p=Process(target=worker,args=(child_pipe,data))
    p.daemon=True
    p.start()

    root.after(500,check_proc)

def check_proc():

    if not main_pipe.poll():
        root.after(500,check_proc)

    else:
        global value_array
        value_array=main_pipe.recv()
```

I'm still not sure if p.join() is needed but the deamon thing seems to get around the zombie-proceses problem

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar problem earlier (except I wasn't using multiprocess). After nearly a whole days research, I come up with the following conclusion:

1. mainloop and `root.waitwindow` will (sometimes) block the sys.exit signal, which your program should receive after you hit ⌘Q.
2. You can bind ⌘Q to a new function, although you may still receive the sys.exit signal
3. Another way (more reliable in my case) is to remap the tcl quitting signal to another function, instead of the default one. You can remap the quit event (dock quit and ⌘Q) using this: `root.createcommand('::tk::mac::Quit',function)`
4. When trying to quit the software, use `sys.exit` instead of `exit()` or `quit()`
5. You can also use `root.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", function)` to define the behavior when users clicking on the red button.
6. You can actually make the border of the window and the three default buttons disappear by flagging `root.overridedirect(1)` and thus force the user to click on a button on your GUI instead of closing the window.